# Problemas com Sockets em chat com host NO-IP

Tags: java, socket

Bom, antes de tudo, eu procurei em vários sites, inclusive aqui, como fazer isso. Testei códigos e modifiquei mas mesmo assim, continuei recebendo erros.

O problema são os sockets para fazer a conexão. Não faço ideia de como usá-los, e eu   preciso criar um programa que funcione como servidor/cliente. Ele enviará algo tipo 5     Strings, para um outro programa que irá fazer umas reorganizações e enviará Strings para um outro servidor/cliente e retornará mais Strings para o primeiro, basicamente ele será um Chat com um Servidor, um `Chat.jar` e um `Servidor.jar`.

Gostaria de fazer o `Servidor.jar` funcionar em um computador **com o no-ip instalado**.

Eis o código que tenho no momento:

```java
Socket clientSocket = null;
BufferedReader inputLine;
PrintStream os = null;
BufferedReader is = null;
InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("servidor.ddns.net", 15980);
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15980);
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    clientSocket = new Socket("servidor.ddns.net", 15980);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    serverSocket.close();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Don't know about host");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host \nServer must be down! NOOO!!");
}
```

Numa forma mais ilustrativa, seria pra ser algo mais ou menos assim:

> Servidor/Cliente¹ ----> Servidor/Cliente Principal ----> Servidor/Cliente²

Depois...

> Servidor/Cliente² ----> Servidor/Cliente Principal ----> Servidor/Cliente¹

O Servidor/Cliente principal seria o `Servidor.Jar` e os outros, `Chat.jar`.

Usando um código parecido com esse código de cima, só recebia a mensagem do "`IOException e`" e de outras formas, recebia algo tipo "`Connect: refused connect`".

Bom... Resumindo, preciso enviar várias Strings, enquanto continuo podendo receber Strings. Não sei como explicar direito e nem como pedir, estou totalmente perdido. Espero que tenham entendido.

OBS: O código do resto do programa está feito. Só está faltando isso.

---

Essa parte do código é nova e já está funcionando normal, agora só sobrou um problema, eu queria trocar de `127.0.0.1`, para uma conexão com o host no-ip, por exemplo: `meuservidor.ddns.net`

Tem como fazer isso? Se sim, como?

```java
Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12342);
System.out.println("O cliente conectou ao servidor");
ObjectOutputStream dados = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
// O código dessa forma está funcionando
dados.writeUTF("Projeto");
dados.writeUTF("Outra Mensagem");
dados.writeUTF("Projeto");

dados.flush();
cliente.close();
```

Esse é o que aparece quando troco o localhost pelo "`meuservidor.ddns.net`" usando essa porta: 12342

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at calc.cliente.main(cliente.java:10)
```

A solução tem de ser algo que não envolva liberar portas no firewall/roteador.

Comment: Eduardo. Adicionei algumas informações sobre o seu erro no final da minha resposta. Vamo que vamo.

Answer (score 5):

O seu código de servidor está bem encaminhado. Mas me parece que sua confusão está em como ele funciona. Vou tentar esclarecer.

Você precisa entender primeiro o modelo de comunicação distribuída via Socket: pense num socket como sendo um canal que conecta dois processos (no caso, duas JVMs), estejam eles em duas máquina separadas ou não. Para a estrutura de rede que usamos desde onde tenho conhecimento, uma máquina é identificada pelo seu IP e um processo dentro de uma máquina é identificado por uma PORTA. Então, se você quiser criar em JAVA um software que "escuta" na porta 7777 (um servidor) e esperar por comunicação externa, você vai usar o objeto ServerSocket:

```
ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket( 7777 );
Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
// Parei pra esperar...
```

Neste caso, quando o código for executado, o `servidor.accept()` vai parar e esperar por uma conexão. Agora você quer que um outro software (ou seja, outra classe a ser executada separadamente) se conecte para mandar mensagens. Basicamente você precisa disso:

```
Socket cliente = new Socket( "127.0.0.1", 7777 );
```

Este código quando executado irá abrir o canal com o servidor (desde que o mesmo esteja executando na mesma máquina (IP = 127.0.0.1). Caso queira outra máquina é só trocar o IP. Só que agora você tem um canal, e precisa passar coisas por dentro dele. No caso do Socket em Java, você tem uma via de mão dupla, ou seja, uma indo do cliente para o servidor e outra do servidor indo para o cliente. Cada via dessas em Java é encapsulada pelos objetos da classe Stream (que são nada mais nada menos que uma sequência de bytes).

Como no seu problema você quer que seu servidor receba Strings, logo depois do canal ser aberto, você precisa pegar o Stream de input (ou seja, de chegada) e fazer uma leitura:

```
InputStream ins = cliente.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(ins);
Object msg = objIn.readObject();
```

Eu usei aqui um `ObjectInputStream` para facilitar a leitura de qualquer objeto do canal. Você pode continuar usando o seu `BufferedReader`. Já do lado cliente, para enviar uma mensagem você precisa de algo assim:

```
OutputStream outs = cliente.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream( outs );
objOut.writeObject( "HELLOOOOO" );
```

Fundamentalmente é isso. O cliente usa o canal de saída (OutputStream) do seu lado do Socket para enviar um objeto, que é o String "HELLOOOOO". Perceba que seu servidor de posse do objeto **msg** pode fazer o que bem entender e depois enviar de volta para o cliente (usando o seu OutputStream).

Para que o servidor se comunique com outro sofware, ele precisará criar um outro Socket. E aí o padrão é o mesmo: ou ele espera nova conexão, ou ele tenta abrir a conexão com alguém que já esteja esperando.

Outros casos bem comuns: (1) para que o seu servidor possa receber várias mensagens de um mesmo cliente, um loop no **readObject** pode ajudar; (2) se seu servidor precisa lidar com vários clientes, o melhor a se fazer é criar uma **Thread** para cada cliente, mas aí é outros 500.

Finalmente, espero que você entenda este conceito, pois ele é fundamentalmente o mesmo para qualquer conexão de rede que usamos hoje: web, torrent, jogo, banco de dados... tudo. Boa sorte!

Se eu puder esclarecer algo mais, pergunta nos comentários.

---

Quanto ao erro "**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused**"; o mesmo está relacionado normalmente à não existência de um ServerSocket disponível no IP:PORTA especificados. Se fosse o caso de seu HOST não estar sendo resolvido para um IP válido o erro possivelmente seria: **UnknownHostException**.

Desta forma, sugiro que faça duas checagens: (1) seu servidor está realmente rodando? (pode parecer bobo, mas como você está testando mais de um cliente, pode ser que ao fechar a primeira conexão o seu servidor tenha fechado); (2) o seu HOST "meuservidor.ddns.net" está realmente sendo resolvido para o IP da máquina onde o servidor está rodando?

Por exemplo: quando eu executo um ping para o nome da minha máquina, o esperado é uma resposta mais ou menos assim `PING minha_maquina (127.0.1.1)`. Quando faço o mesmo para o Google: `PING google.com (173.194.42.163)`. No caso, você tem que ver se o seu `PING meuservidor.ddns.net` resolve para o IP da máquina onde o seu software servidor está rodando.

Comment: Estou trabalhando aqui no código, e já vou editar o tópico em ele, mas por enquanto está dando certo só que com o localhost, como eu faria pra usar o host do no-ip? Tentei trocar o 127.0.0.1 por servidor.ddns.net(Por exemplo), e não deu certo...

Comment: servidor.ddns.net é a mesma máquina que localhost? Se sim, então você precisa checar se este nome realmente está sendo resolvido pelo DNS (um PING deve resolver). Caso não seja, aí você pode estar com algum firewall ativo entre os processos cliente e servidor!

Comment: Nesse caso, é a mesma máquina, mas a intenção é rodar o programa em outras redes também, então abrir portas antes de usar o programa não seria muito viável, e quando você disse "um ping deve resolver" era pra dar ping pelo cmd, e ver se os Packets conseguem retornar?

Comment: Isso. O ping primeiro precisa resolver o nome em IP para depois testar se a máquina responde. Existem ferramentas mais legais para testar a resolução de nomes tipo "trace" e "dig" (mas falo do mundo UNIX). Quanto as portas e firewalls, tem algumas regras para usar portas de números conhecidos que são normalmente abertas como 80 e 8080. O problema é quando elas já estão sendo usadas.

Comment: O ping deu certo, mas colocar "Socket cliente = new Socket("servidor.ddns.net", 8080);" e alterar a do server para 8080, deu erro, isso seria por causa da porta? Se sim, alguma ideia de qual eu usar?

Comment: Qual o erro? Complementa tua pergunta com a pilha de exceção pra eu tentar te ajudar. Abraço.

Comment: Pronto, editei e coloquei o erro.